# C# saving bitmap to jpeg with colour space information

Tags: c#, image, colors, bitmap, jpeg

I've been trying to find a ways to write in information about jpeg colour space information, since regular saving does not do that, and barely anyone talks about it. Part of the code I use to save into jpeg:

```
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bitmapPicture))
        {
            ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
            EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
            bmp.Save(textBox1.Text + "\\" + textBox2.Text + ".jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        }
```

It does the trick, but it doesn't add colour space information which I think is one of the problems when opening that picture with different applications. The colours appears to be incorrect. Also for some reason bitmap brush only uses argb colour space (notice code below). If I'd type in '.FromSrgb' or '.FromRgb' it errors it out (apparently no such thing exists). This is example how I create bitmap which later on is being saved:

```
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapPicture))
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)))
        {
            gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, with, height);
            gfx.DrawImage(addOtherImageOnSameBitmap, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, with2, height2);
        }
```

Also tried doing that with Save File Dialog (code below), but the result is the same - jpeg colours is way off and has no information about colour space.

```
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.Filter = "Images|*.jpg";
        ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Png;
        if (save.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(save.FileName);
            switch (ext)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
            }
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName, format);
        }
```

The problem is fixed when opening that image in photoshop and saving it with sRGB colour space. Is it possible to do that in C#? To save jpeg in sRGB and adding this information to jpeg file itself? Because going into photoshop to fix this problem seems to be a bit too much of a hassle (especially when dealing with a lot of pictures). 
P.S. sorry if posted codes seems somewhat off, I just started learning C# couple days ago.

Comment: All colors in .net are argb. There is a `Color.FromArgb()` overload which just takes R, G and B integers though, which just defaults the alpha to fully opaque (255). Also note that `new Bitmap(Bitmap)` will automatically transform your source image to 32bppargb. That said, jpeg does not support alpha, so it'll be saved as normal RGB anyway. There should be no need to specify that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "The colours appears to be incorrect"? When viewed in what? This is all pretty vague. Show an example.

Comment: Well the term 'incorrect colours' is pretty much self explanatory. You put original file, pass it through the written program and as you open the image saved by the C# program - it's not exactly the same image, because colours are different comparing to the original. And it doesn't matter in what program it was viewed, it always should set the correct colour profile (sRGB), since it doesn't add that information with the saved file I assume any program can interpret picture however it wants.

Comment: Here's an example: In this case it was viewed in windows picture viewer, picasa, photoshop, etc. Same result (since colours varies from screen to screen I took a photo of my screen with my phone) [link](https://scontent.fvno3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/28001187_2021257424556695_43252522_n.jpg?oh=c4f50416dd8fa818784aa093fe338473&oe=5A8327B9) Again problem goes away if I save that file again in photoshop as sRGB, which adds colour space information to the file, but I want to do that in C#.

Comment: Picture on the left is original and picture on the right is generated by c# program. It's not much different, but it's enough to ruin skin tones and make it look like person in the picture has some sort of disease.

Comment: Isn't that just due to the lossy jpeg compression though? Jpeg always ruins red tints if the compression level is too high. Default on .Net is apparently "quality level" (a kind of inverted "compression level" setting) 75%

Comment: I don't think so. Quality level is set to 100 % (see code above), besides, why then problem goes away if I re-save the same file generated by c# program in photoshop with sRGB profile? If it's lossy compression, then photoshop has no way to get back that information, but it does correct colours without doing anything else other than re-saving same file.

Comment: No idea. I'm not in the habit of saving as anything but PNG.